# is hidden selector return true on blank element

Tags: jquery, hidden

Why :hidden selector return true on blank element?

```
<span class="xxx">
    <span class="a"/>
    <span class="b"/>
</span>

<span class="yyy" style="display: none;">
    <span class="a"/>
    <span class="b"/>
</span>

console.log($('span.xxx').is(':hidden'));
console.log($('span.yyy').is(':hidden'));
```

Print **two true**

How i can select only elements with display: none?

Comment: Side note:  Assuming you're using HTML, not XHTML, your markup is invalid. `span` elements are not void elements, so you cannot use the `<span/>` syntax with them. It **must** be `<span></span>`. Only **void** elements (like `<br>`) can optionally have the `/` before the `>`. (But that's not why those spans are hidden.)

Comment: ok, understand, but how i can select id=xxx? i use module which print this structure - "blank" or hidden span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `span` has `0` height/width dimensions due to there being no content. This means that the element is technically invisible despite the fact that neither `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` are set on it.

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/):

> An element is assumed to be hidden if it or any of its parents consumes no space in the document.

Once you add some visible content to the element it works correctly:

```js
console.log($('span.xxx').is(':hidden'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="xxx">
    <span class="a">A</span>
    <span class="b">B</span>
</span>

<span class="yyy" style="display: none;">
    <span class="a">A</span>
    <span class="b">B</span>
</span>
```

Comment: @Unknow.Vagrant: Rory answered *the question you asked*. If you have a different question, post a different question.